# Dependency that doesnt have setup.py

Tags: python, dependencies, setup.py

I am trying to specify a dependency in my setup.py file to code that exists only on Github. I have read about using `dependency_links` to get setup.py to install the module, but the code I want to use doesn't include a setup.py of it's own. Is there any way to automatically satisfy that dependency when I run setup.py?

If it matters, the code in question that I would like to use is https://github.com/tpircher/pycrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think that can be done easily.  The simplest way to depend on pycrc is to ask its maintainer to add proper Python packaging.